# Create button in C# winform like IDM buttons

Tags: winforms, button

Did you see the first page of IDM (Internet Download Manager)??

[IDM first form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nuRJ.png)

Now i'm trying to build some buttons like these buttons(above picture) but I don't know how I must start? Is there any software for it? These buttons change their mode when hover mouse on them. 
Have nice day

Comment: It is the olden style for toolbars.  Still available in Winforms.  Right-click the toolbox > Choose Items > .NET Framework Components tab > tick "Toolbar".  You must bring the icons for the "buttons" yourself, how well that looks greatly depends on your icon design/theft skills.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a ToolStrip control and add a Button to it using the DropDown control on it.  Change the DisplayStyle to ImageAndText, and TextImageRelation to ImageAboveText.  Now change the Image property to your Icon image, and ImageScaling to None.

On the ToolStrip itself, change GripStyle to Hidden.